# iOS integration app with FB API

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

While sending app with FBSDK to iTunes Connect, Xcode reports:

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
This action could not be completed. Try again.
```

Application Loader say more:

```
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle xxx [Payload/xxx.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
```

Linked frameworks:

```
FBSDKCoreKit
FBSDKShareKit
FBSDKLikeKit
```

Code in delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application                              didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
             openURL:url
             sourceApplication:sourceApplication
             annotation:annotation];
}
```

in MainViewController:

```
FBSDKLikeControl *likeButtonFB = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
if(likeButtonFB)
{   likeButtonFB.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/";
    likeButtonFB.center = self.view.center;
    likeButtonFB.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
    [self.view addSubview:likeButtonFB];
}
```

If few FBSDK code lines are rem. then all is ok.
What kind of permission, and where, must I include to the provisioning profile?

**EDIT**

Strange solution, but problem partially resolved.
All of my apps in App Store, many builds, are signed like this:

[image]

As I wrote, when app is compiled with FBSDK frameworks, App Loader & Xcode shows errors.

After change:

[image]

Xcode still is unable to send app, but Application Loader do it.

Comment: Without FBSDK code all is ok. My apps stay in App Store.

Comment: This error message says, that you aren't setting the distribution provisioning profile in the code signing. It's not about FBSDK

Comment: No. When I remove FBSDK frameworks and rem FBSDK code, nothing more change in Xcode - all is OK,